# How do I combine similar method calls into a delegate pattern?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have three methods:

```
public void Save<T>(T entity)
{
    using (new Transaction())
    {
        Session.Save(entity);
    }
}

public void Create<T>(T entity)
{
    using (new Transaction())
    {
        Session.Create(entity);
    }
}

public void Delete<T>(T entity)
{
    using (new Transaction())
    {
        Session.Delete(entity);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the only thing that differs is the method call inside the `using` block. How can I rewrite this so it's something like this instead:

```
public void Save<T>(T entity)
{
    TransactionWrapper(Session.Save(entity));
}

public void Create<T>(T entity)
{
    TransactionWrapper(Session.Create(entity));
}

public void Save<T>(T entity)
{
    TransactionWrapper(Session.Save(entity));
}
```

So in other words, I pass a method call as a parameter, and the `TransactionWrapper` method wraps a transaction around the method call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an [Action<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) to a method to specify an action to execute:

```
private void ExecuteInTransaction<T>(Action<T> action, T entity)
{
    using (new Transaction())
    {
        action(entity);
    }
}

public void Save<T>(T entity)
{
    ExecuteInTransaction(Session.Save, entity);
}
```

But IMO this isn't a worthy improvement over your original code if your *ExecuteInTransaction* method isn't more complex.

Comment: Thanks, it works great. I wanted to wrap the method calls in a transaction method so I can easily enable/disable transactions across all 3 methods in only one place.